# don't show iframe on recommend

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I integrated the recommend button to my website.
If I click the button, it is opening a frame with my photo and the comment option. (see image below)

I don't need the comment option, and I dont want it to be shown on a click to the button.

The code I am using is:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" href="myurl.dom/">;
```

How can I disable the frame which opens when I click on the recommend button?

Can anyone help me?

ty.

[image]

Comment: <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" href="http://myurl.dom/">

Comment: please edit your question and put the code there. Please also explain it more clear as I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a consistent way to hide this, but CSS can solve most, if not all, problems.

Looking at the code, it will actually add a span to your code, and in that an iFrame. Not displaying the span will solve your problem. This way, the box is still there, but your user will never see it. This is untested, but should work.

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried something similar, but it didn't work - although yours is working fine.